# How can I turn a Vec of trait objects into a tree structure?

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I'm trying to implement the BVH algorithm in my Rust ray tracer, but I'm having trouble with lifetimes and ownership. I have a trait `Hittable` that a bunch of different things implement -- `Sphere`, `Triangle`, `Mesh`, etc. And so I have a `Vec<Box<dyn Hittable>>`, which I want to turn into a tree of this struct:

```
pub struct BvhNode {
    bounding_box: BoundingBox,
    left: Box<dyn Hittable>,
    right: Box<dyn Hittable>,
}
```

And so I have this recursive algorithm that *almost* works, if not for lifetime issues. My function looks like

```
    pub fn new(objects: Vec<Box<dyn Hittable>>, start: usize, end: usize, t0: f64, t1: f64) -> Self {
        let r = util::rand();
        let comp = if r < 1. / 3. {
            util::box_x_compare
        } else if r < 2. / 3. {
            util::box_y_compare
        } else {
            util::box_z_compare
        }; // which axis to compare along (random for now)
        let num_obj = end - start;
        let mut left: Box<dyn Hittable>;
        let mut right: Box<dyn Hittable>;
        if num_obj == 1 {
            left = objects[start];
            right = objects[start];
        } else if num_obj == 2 {
            if comp(&&objects[start], &&objects[start + 1]) != Ordering::Greater {
                left = objects[start];
                right = objects[start + 1];
            } else {
                left = objects[start + 1];
                right = objects[start];
            }
        } else {
            let mut slice: Vec<&Box<dyn Hittable>> = Vec::new();
            for i in start..end { // make a copy to sort
                slice.push(&objects[i]);
            }
            slice.sort_by(comp);
            let mid = start + num_obj / 2;
            let l = BvhNode::new(objects, start, mid, t0, t1);
            let r = BvhNode::new(objects, mid, end, t0, t1);
            left = Box::new(l.clone());
            right = Box::new(r.clone());
        }

        let left_box = left.get_bounding_box(t0, t1);
        let right_box = right.get_bounding_box(t0, t1);
        
        if left_box.is_none() || right_box.is_none() {
            println!("Error: No bounding box in Bvh Node");
            panic!();
        }

        Self { left, right, bounding_box: BoundingBox::new(Point3::origin(), Point3::origin()) }
    }
```

First, I ran into some issues with trying to "move out of a vec", which I can't do, so I tried to implement `Clone` on all of the types that implement `Hittable`. It works for almost all of them, but my `Triangle` struct

```
pub struct Triangle <'b> {
    mat: &'b Box<dyn Material>,
    bounding_box: Option<BoundingBox>,
    p: Vec<Point3<f64>>,
    n: Vec<Vector3<f64>>,
    uv: Vec<Vector2<f64>>,
}
```

contains reference to the material of its associated mesh, which clone doesn't like. I *could* make a clone of the Material itself, but it could potentially be very large and I don't want to have thousands of copies  of it for each triangle in a mesh.

I feel like there has to be a better way to design my system, like get rid of references in `Triangle` so it can easily be copied. Once this structure is created, I won't need the `Vec` anymore, so being able to `move` the objects to out of it inside of copying them would also work, but I don't see a way to do that either.

In case it helps, the full file is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/calvin-godfrey/RustRaytracer/blob/master/src/hittable.rs)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing the `objects` Vec to `&mut Vec<Box<dyn Hittable>>` and then using `objects.remove()` instead of indexing into it. I had to change the algorithm slightly to handle the new way, but it should work.